# How to disable popup which shows that Adobe Flash Player is not updated?

Tags: java, flash, firefox, pdf, selenium-webdriver

I have two questions regarding issue with FirefoxProfile(I've spent a lot of time digging in the Internet so finally I have to ask here).

**PROBLEM NR 1:** I have to deal with a Flash animation using Selenium WebDriver(Java) with Firefox. For this particular reason I cooperate with Sikuli and it works fine.

The problem is that from time to time my test fails due to the fact that Adobe Flash Player is not updated and firefox throws a warning about this situation.
I suppose that I have to change something in the profile but I was searching for exact preferences but any success.

**QUESTION NR 1:** Is this possible? If so what I have to change?

**PROBLEM NR 2:** I would like to take this opportunity and ask second question: 
My second goal is to open PDF file after click on a link(currently a new system window appears with information what I want to do -open/save and so one). Okey- I can deal with saving a file with this main preference and few more:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
```

but when I want to use:

```
profile.setPrefernce("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/pdf")
```

still this system window(with question about open/save) appears.

**QUESTION NR 2:** What I have to add to that line above to open a PDF file in a new browser window and preview it?

Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!
Update: anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to wait till alert pops up as below (max 60 seconds),

```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
  .ignoring(NoAlertPresentException.class)
  .until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

After alert pop up, you can dismiss alert,

```
   driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```